# How to turn JOINS into Subqueries without breaking the SQL logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery

I have performance issues while using multiple joins in T-SQL and if anyone can help me to turn these joins into sub-queries would be nice.

Whenever i try to change the join into subquery, i'm loosing the name declaration for the specific table. For instance if i try to turn the Album join (which is the first join on code below) into subquery i'm loosing the alias "AS a" and the "a.Title AS Album" stopped working so i have no idea how this would be done. If anyone gives me an example how should it work for one of the cases i suppose i will be able to reconstruct all of them.

> SQL

```
SELECT
    t.TrackId, 
    t.[Name] AS Track, 
    a.Title AS Album, 
    aa.[Name] AS Artist, 
    p.[Name] AS Playlist,
    m.[Name] AS MediaType,
    il.UnitPrice AS InvoicePrice,
    CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerName,
    CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS ResponsibleEmployeeName
FROM dbo.Track AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.Album AS a
    ON t.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
INNER JOIN dbo.Artist AS aa
    ON a.ArtistId = aa.ArtistId
INNER JOIN dbo.PlaylistTrack AS plt
    ON t.TrackId = plt.TrackId
INNER JOIN dbo.Playlist AS p
    ON p.PlaylistId = plt.PlaylistId
INNER JOIN dbo.MediaType AS m
    ON t.MediaTypeId = m.MediaTypeId
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine AS il
    ON t.TrackId = il.TrackId
INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i
    ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS c
    ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS e
    ON c.SupportRepId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE m.[Name] LIKE '%audio%'
ORDER BY t.[Name] ASC
```

Comment: There are a lot of joins there. The optimiser may not be able to find the best plan for the query. Can you post a picture of the query plan?

Comment: turn join  in subquery for performance ? .. seems not a good idea ..

Comment: `m.[Name] LIKE '%audio%'` is going to be a problem for performance as well. Can you post the indexes on your tables?

Comment: Its kind of hard to post the query plan because its really huge, but the indexes are basically all the primary keys that i'm using for joining the tables. Why '%audio%' would slow down the performance ?

Comment: @S.Minchev Using `like` with a pattern that starts with a wildcard, e.g. `%`, precludes using an index seek to locate matching rows. It's like asking you to find all the words in a dictionary that contain "arf", but you don't know what the words start with. The only way is to perform a _scan_ rather than a _seek_. Tip: See [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to add an execution plan to your question.

Comment: @HABO Great tip, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of a subqyery you mean? Something like:

```
SELECT t.TrackId, 
    t.[Name] AS Track, 
    (SELECT title FROM dbo.Album WHERE AlbumId = t.AlbumId) AS AlbumTitle
```

That's not going if you remove the join to `Album`, because you need the album reference to get to artist. If you want to join a subquery, you can do that, and keep the alias:

```
SELECT
    t.TrackId, 
    t.[Name] AS Track, 
    a.Title AS Album, 
    aa.[Name] AS Artist, 
    p.[Name] AS Playlist,
    m.[Name] AS MediaType,
    il.UnitPrice AS InvoicePrice,
    CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerName,
    CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS ResponsibleEmployeeName
FROM dbo.Track AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Album) AS a
   ON t.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
   -- rest of joins
```

But logically, this is exactly the same as you have right now, and there will be no difference in the plan generated by the query optimizer. Even this:

```
SELECT
    t.TrackId, 
    t.[Name] AS Track, 
    aa.Title AS Album, -- note change here
    aa.[Name] AS Artist, 
    p.[Name] AS Playlist,
    m.[Name] AS MediaType,
    il.UnitPrice AS InvoicePrice,
    CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerName,
    CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS ResponsibleEmployeeName
FROM dbo.Track AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT alb.Title
                 , art.Name
                 , alb.AlbumId
              FROM dbo.Album alb
        INNER JOIN dbo.Artist art
                ON art.ArtistId = alb.ArtistID) AS aa
   ON t.AlbumId = aa.AlbumId
INNER JOIN dbo.PlaylistTrack AS plt
   ON t.TrackId = plt.TrackId
-- rest of them
```

Will produce the exact same plan. We might have moved `Album` <-> `Artist` join to a joined subquery, but essentially, it's still the same thing - inner joins.

Nothing like that will help with your performance. What might help you is to create indexes on these tables. If this is the kind of query you execute a lot, you can also create an indexed view, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW BoughtTracks
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    il.InvoiceLineId, -- I'm guessing here, we need a unique ID
    t.TrackId, 
    t.[Name] AS Track, 
    a.Title AS Album, 
    aa.[Name] AS Artist, 
    p.[Name] AS Playlist,
    m.[Name] AS MediaType,
    il.UnitPrice AS InvoicePrice,
    CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerName,
    CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS ResponsibleEmployeeName
FROM dbo.Track AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.Album AS a
    ON t.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
INNER JOIN dbo.Artist AS aa
    ON a.ArtistId = aa.ArtistId
INNER JOIN dbo.PlaylistTrack AS plt
    ON t.TrackId = plt.TrackId
INNER JOIN dbo.Playlist AS p
    ON p.PlaylistId = plt.PlaylistId
INNER JOIN dbo.MediaType AS m
    ON t.MediaTypeId = m.MediaTypeId
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine AS il
    ON t.TrackId = il.TrackId
INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i
    ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS c
    ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS e
    ON c.SupportRepId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE m.[Name] LIKE '%audio%'

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ux ON BoughtTracks (InvoiceLineId);
```

This will slow down inserts to these tables, but selecting on `BoughtTracks` will be fast (you can also create additional indexes on that view), something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM BoughtTracks WITH (NOEXPAND) -- NOEXPAND is important
 WHERE CustomerName = 'Joe Smith'
```

Could execute orders of magnitude faster than your current query, depending of course on the size of your data. Especially if you create an index on it

```
CREATE INDEX ix_CustomerName ON BoughtTracks (CustomerName) 
INCLUDE (...) -- maybe include some columns you know you will need when querying for CustomerName
WHERE (...) -- maybe there are alsways accompanying predicates when querying for CustomerName
```

Comment: That looks really interesting, will try it out immediately

Comment: The only problem would be this view, cuz i'm constantly inserting new data into track table - in every 2 minutes lets say, so i'd need a trigger as well in order to populate the view

Comment: You don't need a trigger, this is not a table. A view is just like a saved select query, with an index it gets materialized, sort of like a table but SQL Server will take care of updating it.

Answer (score 1):

Turn a join in subquery could be not the best solution

assuming you have already the index for foreign key for each retaled  table

```
table  Artist index on column (ArtistId)
table  PlaylistTrack index on column (TrackId)
table  Playlist index on column (PlaylistId)
table  MediaType index  on column ( MediaTypeId )
.....
```

for performance  be sure you have index  on

```
table  track a composite index  on column  (AlbumId, TrackId, MediaTypeId )
table  Album  a cmposite index  on column ( AlbumId, ArtistId )
```